# rails images in stylesheets (from vendor) - do I need to modify all of the libraries (huge css files) from img.png to asset-url(img.png)?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I think we need to load images like this in stylesheets - `asset-url(image.png)`.

This is ok for stylesheets, images that we load manually.

But for images loaded by libraries like tablesorter, do I need to edit the stylesheet and replace `image.png` with `asset-url(image.png)`?

Answer (score 0):

So I also ran into this issue, and long story short I had to modify my libraries

If your libraries are in `app/assets`, `lib/assets`, or `vendor/assets`, then they're going to be affected by the [asset-pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

For the library's css files (any that referenced other assets), I had to convert the CSS to SASS because `asset-url` is used in SASS so `file.css` became `file.css.scss`

For the library's js files, I had to rename some of them (any that referenced images) from `file.js` to `file.js.erb` and then any assets used there I has to use `<%= asset_path("library/file.jpg") %>`

You can avoid using the asset pipeline by putting your libraries in `public/assets` directly I believe but you won't get the benefits of the asset pipeline in production.

Hope this helps.